# Non Distinct Eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If the Eigenvalues are not distinct like in this problem I have attached i.e the eigenvectors are not linearly dependent because of that?  and does that change the answer? please clear my doubt[image]

Comment: Consider trying out mathjax for your problems to format them, and welcome to MSE!

Comment: Hint: for an upper triangle matrix the eigenvalues are always on the diagonal. So as you noticed they are 2 and 1.

Comment: @Javed:  Hi, I was wondering the same thing myself, whether non distinct eigenvalues correspond to linearly dependent eigenvectors.   I believe the answer to this question is that this is not necessarily the case.  See the fourth sentence of Example 3.7.1 in the following link: http://www.jirka.org/diffyqs/htmlver/diffyqsse22.html.  To anyone more knowledgable than me, please correct me if I am wrong...

Answer (score 2):

Eigen vectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are necessarily independent.Also $x_2$ can't be an eigenvector since it is $0$.

When you solve, you find  the eigen space $E_2$ has dimension $1$, with basis $x_1$. You complete it in a basis of the  generalised eigenspace, which happens to be $\ker(A-2I)^2$. For instance, you may solve for 
$$(A-2I)x=x_1$$
One finds $\begin{bmatrix}x\\\frac12\\\frac12\end{bmatrix}$. If you don't want denominators you may  as well set, say:
$$x_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I can't deduce from your profile whether like me you are more exposed to French terminology than to English terminology, but I found to my surprise that in English, [characteristic (sub)space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Overview) is just a synonym for eigenspace, not a name for the generalised notion. Given two distinct adjectives and two distinct notions, why not let both adjectives designate the same, least useful, one of the two?

Comment: I am more exposed indeed. I thought this kind of terminology was normalised. It's good to know anyway.